# How to set time to "keep synchronized with internet servers" in Lubuntu

Tags: lubuntu, lxde, time, timezone

I'm having hard time making my Lubuntu realise daylight savings has started. I was told to go to "Menu->System Tools->Time and Date" so that I can adjust my time zone and enable "keep synchronized with internet servers". The thing is; I can't find "time and date" under system tools!

Comment: I think you have to install 'ntp'. At least that's what XFCE does.  'sudo apt-get install ntp'

Comment: I even changed the /etc/ntp.conf file but no changes came

Answer (score 5):

If you cannot find Time and Date, you can also use the terminal.

1. Open the LXTerminal
2. Enter

   sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata

   You will be asked for your password
3. Follow the directions in the terminal.

Comment: that is not working for me since my time is extended with 40 minutes with respect to Asia/Kolkata timezone. I am not getting the exact time of indian servers

Comment: not working either

Comment: Worked great for me. BIOS time setting opens up inside terminal. Easy to choose time zone and then clock corrected itself.